# he would be quite within the law to do that

Tags: meaning-in-context

‘Well, dear, I think you’ll find that **he would be quite within the law to do that**, even if, er, he maybe would have done better to, um, tell his wife the truth …

From Harry Potter

Should it have been "**it** would be quite within the law to do that"?

"He would be quite within the law to do that" seems like **he** is legal.

Comment: "He," the actor, is  acting within the limits of the law, just as we say "He broke the law."

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Is "quite within the law" connected to "to do that"? I mean, is  "quite within the law" a prepositional phrase for "to do that"? I wonder what "to" means here.

Comment: "In doing that, he would still be within the bounds of what is legal."